# Return multiple data/responsetext from an XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php

I have a js function that calls in an xml request to fetch data from a separate php file. I can get a returned data through `echoing` it from the separate php file.

Here's my current code:

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
            //On Data Receive
            countryHeader.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "country.php?c=" + countryName, true);
    xhttp.send();
```

And on my php:

```php
    include("conn.php");

    $c = htmlentities($_GET["c"]);
    $sec_country = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $c);

    //Searches the db
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE country_code = '$sec_country' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count == 1)
    {
        //Get Data
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $countryName = $row['country_name'];
        $countryPrice = $row['country_price'];
        echo $countryName." is worth $".$countryPrice;
    }
    else
    {
        //Invalid Code/No Data
        echo "No Country Found";
    }
```

If I send in a country code for example like `rus`, it would return `Russia is worth $1B` mainly from the  `echo $countryName." is worth $".$countryPrice;`
But what if I want to separately send `$countryName` and `$countryPrice`?

For example `responseText.a` and `responseText.b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send JSON response from PHP. Here is a reference -> https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)
On the tutorial, it's missing a `$myObj = new stdClass();` on the php side to initialize it. If you won't place that it would generate some warning and the js side won't work.